# How to set the format_mask of the to_char( value, format_mask ) function in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

How to set the `format_mask` of the

> **to_char( value, format_mask )**

function in **postgreSQL** to convert a number to a character if I don't know what number can be in the database, for example 0.00125 or 1111 or -1999.8888?
And get the same values ​​in the string representation with an accuracy of 4 characters after the separator?

I assume `format_mask` should be set like this:

```
SELECT to_char(-0.1918123, '999999990.9999');
```

Maybe there is a more universal / correct option?

Just as interesting, is it somehow possible to get a string with exactly the same number of characters after the separator, which is passed to the function without adding extra zeros to the end?

Comment: Why not just cast the column to text? `the_column::text`

Comment: Very simple way: `SELECT round(-0.1918123, 4)` will be return -0.1918